# How to get image file name in a textbox?

Tags: c#, file, directory, fileinfo, imagelist

I have a problem about C# file name. I show some pictures with PictureBox. Also I want to write picture's name in a TextBox. I search fileinfo, directoryinfo, but it doesnt work.

```
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
 images.Add(Properties.Resources.baseball_bat);
 images.Add(Properties.Resources.bracelet);
 images.Add(Properties.Resources.bride);

pictureBox1.Image = images[..];
```

and i want to write baseball_bat, bride, bracelet etc. in a TextBox. What can I do? any offer?

Comment: Are your images all from `Properties.Resources` or that's just an example ?

Comment: It's a little example. If there are any alternatives i can try it. I just write picture's names..

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can save both the name and the image together, such that when you retrieve one element you have both the name and the image. But probably you should specify the source of the images, to understand if it's feasible for you an approach like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is already built in...

Image lists store their images in a way that you can reference them by name and return the image.

Single use :

```
private string GetImageName(ImageList imglist, int index)
    {
        return imglist.Images.Keys[index].ToString();
    }
```

This returns the name of the image at the passed index

Store values for later on :

```
private Dictionary<int, string> GetImageNames(ImageList imglist)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        int salt = 0;

        foreach (var item in imglist.Images.Keys)
        {
            dict.Add(salt, item.ToString());
            salt++;
        }
        return dict;
    }
```

This returns a dictionary that references the index of picture to their string name in the image list.

Once again this is built in there is no need to try to extend funct. to it...

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the simplest methods is saving both the name and the image in a `List<KeyValuePair<string,Image>>` or `IDictionary<string,image>`.

Here's an example using a `IDictionary<string,image>`
(I decided for `SortedList<>` because of the indexing) :

```
var images = new SortedList<string, Image>();
images.Add("baseball_bat", Properties.Resources.baseball_bat);
images.Add("bracelet", Properties.Resources.bracelet);
...

// when you show the first image...
pictureBox1.Image = images.Values[0];
textBox1.Text = images.Keys[0];

// when you show the nth image...
pictureBox1.Image = images.Values[n];
textBox1.Text = images.Keys[n];
```

For a `List<KeyValuePair<string,Image>>` would be:

```
var images = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Image>>();
images.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,Image>("baseball_bat", Properties.Resources.baseball_bat));
images.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,Image>("bracelet", Properties.Resources.bracelet));
...

// when you show the first image...
pictureBox1.Image = images[0].Values;
textBox1.Text = images[0].Keys;

// when you show the nth image...
pictureBox1.Image = images[n].Values;
textBox1.Text = images[n].Keys;
```

Comment: OK. I used List<KeyValuePair<string,Image>> and i write that
images.Add("bracelet", Properties.Resources.bracelet);
Where is the wrong? I think we close solution.

Comment: @physee: Using a list of kvpair is different from a dictionary. I edited the question to make it clear. Please note the difference in the `Add(...)` methods and the accessing `[...]`

Comment: I did it.
SortedList<string, Image> images = new SortedList<string, Image>();
Thanks a lot...

Comment: But i have a bit problem. When I run code, after 2 click, "An entry with the same key already exists." said. what's the problem? :/

Comment: @physee: You are adding the same image multiple times in the `SortedList<>`. This structure (like all dictionaries) allows only one entry for the same key. If you need to add multiple images having the same name, you should switch to `List<>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the resources along with their keys (names of the resources) by using reflection:

```
//a helper dictionary if you want to save the images and their names for later use
var namesAndImages = new Dictionary<String, Image>();

var resourcesSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);

        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry myResource in resourcesSet)
        {
            if (myResource.Value is Image) //is this resource is associated with an image
            {
                String resName = myResource.Key.ToString(); //get resource's name
                Image resImage = myResource.Value as Image; //get the Image itself

                namesAndImages.Add(resName, resImage);
            }
        }

        //now you can use the values saved in the dictionary and easily get their names
        ...
```

**Update:** I've updated the code to save the values in a dictionary, so you can conveniently use them later.

Comment: Using the code I've posted, you can get images along with their names, so when you set an image, you can set its name as well.